# problems with proxy in vscode

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

I'm testing VSCode by first time and I configure my proxy in settings.json as recommended:

> "http.proxy": "[http://domain\user:pass@myproxy:port/](http://domain%5Cuser:pass@myproxy:port/)"

But it doesn't work when I try to install new extensions I get a connected timeout error. I also try to configure the proxy as system environment variable with the same result.
Could you help me? Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?
Is there another way to download extensions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Same problem here. It used to work but now in version 1.8.1 the log shows `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED`

Comment: They added a new setting to the configuration named "http.proxyAuthorization" but this does not work. I found that someone already reported it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17502

Answer (score 12):

1. start vscode with below command

   > code --proxy-server="xxx.xx.xx.xx:port"
2. add command in desktop for vscode

   /usr/share/applications/code.desktop

   > Exec=/usr/share/code/code --proxy-server="xx.x.x.xx:xxx" --unity-launch %F

Comment: Took me so long to get to this. TNX

Comment: on Mac VSCode located in /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin , so run as "./code <rest of command>"

Answer (score 9):

Setting Up VS code behind proxy (Proxy script pac file) in Windows 10 to install extensions and updates

1. Locate the Proxy script path from
   `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`
2. From the proxy pac file locate the proxy server domain name/port details (chose one that allows internet connection if there are many)
3. In VS Code go to **File > Preferences > Settings** and search for "Proxy"
4. Enter the proxy server url in the **Http: Proxy (http.proxy)** setting field
5. Un-tick check box for **Http: Proxy Strict SSL ( http.proxyStrictSSL)**
6. Restart VS code

Comment: First, you forgot to start with: Open a terminal window and start the Registry Editor by typing "regedit"
Second, the "Software" (on my machine) is all caps: "SOFTWARE".
Third, there is no "proxy pac" under Name or Type.  There *is* a mention of in the "Data" column, at the end of a url containing the server domain name (e.g.127.0.0.1) and port (e.g. 64730).
Finally, how can I get VS Code loaded in the first place to change its Proxy if I can't run it in WSL Ubuntu in the first place? (answer: Turn off the VPN temporarily).
Finally, call code from Ubuntu, not Windows.

Answer (score 5):

In VS code: File -> Preferences ->Settings.

```
 {
    "http.proxyStrictSSL":false,
    "http.proxy":"http://USERID:PASSWORD@proxy.domain.com:3128"
 }
```

It works for me. And will work for you too. It appears that in http.proxy you have added "domain" after "http://" which is not required.

Answer (score 3):

I was having issues too. Try adding:

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

to your settings.json file.

Comment: Did this resolve the issue ? For me it does not seem to work unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2):

As @Yan QiDonge mentioned you can do that.

But if you want to have a more generic solution, this is what I did.
What I did was, I went to **Internet Options => Connections => LAN Settings**, and then I checked the "Automatically detect setting" and un-checked all other boxes. and it worked like a charm!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Windows 7.

Change the system proxy to your proxy, like `localhost:3128`, in **Internet Options** => **Connections** => **LAN Settings**.

After a version (1.35.0 maybe), the proxy settings in the **Settings** of vscode seems not working.
My proxy is down as soon as I update.
Finally, I fixed the problem by changing the system proxy.

An official reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network

Comment: Thanks, your solution gave me an idea to make it a more generic solution. What I did was, I went to Internet Options => Connections => LAN Settings, and then I checked the "Automatically detect setting" and un-checked all other boxes. and it worked like a charm!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just by Googling I came across this psudie disclaimer about extensions not being able to benefit from proxy support in VSCode:

> Legacy proxy server support Extensions don't benefit yet from the same
> proxy support that VS Code supports. You can follow this issue's
> development in GitHub.
>
> Similarly to extensions, a few other VS Code features don't yet fully
> support proxy networking, namely the CLI interface. The CLI interface
> is what you get when running code --install-extension vscodevim.vim
> from a command prompt or terminal. You can follow this issue's
> development in GitHub.
>
> Due to both of these constraints, the http.proxy, http.proxyStrictSSL
> and http.proxyAuthorization variables are still part of VS Code's
> settings, yet they are only respected in these two scenarios.

However using ctrl+comma
[image]

It seems to be easiest way with maximum result! Even cadmium works
although there is a github issue :
[CLI proxy support #29910](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/29910)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yarn run this command it worked for me

"yarn config set strict-ssl false"

This worked for me