# "Error while fetching extensions. XHR Failed"

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

I can't install extensions and net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED.
How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try disabling `http.proxyStrinctSSL` as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404000/problems-with-proxy-in-vscode